# Combining translation of Quran package line by line with its original Arabic text

Tags: arabic, xepersian

I want to place the Persian translation of quran package =`\quransurahfa*[1]`  right below the original text=`\quransurah*[1]` of this code :

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[trans=fa]{quran}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=0.7]{Yas}

\newfontfamily\Amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}


\begin{document}
\begin{arab}
\noindent\Amiri\quransurah*[1]
\end{arab}
\noindent
\quransurahfa*[1]
\end{document}
```

which produces :
[image]

to appear like this:

[image]

Comment: There is no way (at least no easy way) to make linebreak of translation respect linebreak of the original text.

Comment: @touhami If sacrifice this feature, how could just make the lines combinated, not exactly word by word or number by number?

Comment: you can try something like [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20901/breakable-vboxes/20903#20903). I'll give it a try, but not to night :-) sorry!

Comment: All right, thanks.

Comment: Maybe something could be done with the `expex` package. But `\quransurah` is not expandable, so I think you'd need to enter your text directly for it to work.

Comment: Dear @DavidPurton, thanks for your comment. I'm not familiar with that package. If do so (manually add both original and translated texts), could you provide an example ?

Comment: Is there significance in the colours?

Comment: @DavidPurton: No actually, the only important thing is that the numbered sentences end at the same time.

Comment: I can't understand Arabic or Persian. Can you point me to a source that shows me what should line up with what for (say) Surah 1 (e.g., where there are two Persian words for one Arabic word)? I'll have a working example for you shortly.

Comment: @DavidPurton: I can't show what you want, so please do it at you supposition.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an attempt at doing this with the `expex` package which is especially for linguistics.

## Updated answer using `\quranayah`

You can use `\quranayah[1][1]` to insert each *ayah*. The problem is that the whole *ayah* is placed in a box which can't be broken across lines. So if you leave things justified you will get ugly overfull or underfull boxes everywhere. You could also try using `\raggedleft` but this doesn't look great either. My best option is to use a combination of `\quranayah` and manually broken lines as shown in the following MWE. I've adjusted a few other spacing settings to improve the output.

### MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usepackage[trans=fa]{quran}
\usepackage{expex}
\makeatletter
\lingset{%
  everygl=\def\qt@no##1{ \hfill ##1},
  everygla=\arabicfont\large\rule{0pt}{5ex},
  everyglb=\footnotesize,
  glrightskip=0pt,
  glhangstyle=none,
  glspace=.5em plus 3em minus .15em
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

\begingl
  \gla
    \quranayah*[1][1]
    \quranayah*[1][2]
    \quranayah*[1][3]
    \quranayah*[1][4]
    \quranayah*[1][5]
    {اهدِنَا الصِّراطَ} {المُستَقيمَ \hfill ﴿٦﴾}
    \quranayah*[1][7]
    //
  \glb
    \quranayahfa*[1][1]
    \quranayahfa*[1][2]
    \quranayahfa*[1][3]
    \quranayahfa*[1][4]
    \quranayahfa*[1][5]
    {ما را به راه راست} {هدايت فرما، \hfill (6)}
    \quranayahfa*[1][7]
    //
\endgl

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

## Original answer

Sorry that I've probably lined up the words wrong as I don't understand Arabic or Persian.

One issue is that I'm having trouble changing the line spacing. It seems to be the same issue as [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/215283/controling-spacing-between-wrapped-gloss-lines-in-expex). I've used the same work-around as in that question.

There are lots of options for controlling these structures in `expex`. Have a look at §9 of the manual.

### MWE

I used the Qur'an text and Farsi translation from `qurantext-simple.def` and `qurantext-fa.translation.def` respectively.

I gave up at *ayah* 5 because *ayah* 6 was too confusing for me to decide what should go under what :).

I was unable to get it working with the `quran` package for the text. I think this is because `\quransurah` is not expandable.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont{Yas}

\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\usepackage{expex}
\lingset{everygla=\arabicfont\large\rule{0pt}{25pt}, everyglb=\footnotesize,
  glwordalign=center}

\begin{document}

\begingl
  \gla بِسمِ اللَّهِ الرَّحمٰنِ الرَّحيمِ ۝١
    الحَمدُ لِلَّهِ رَبِّ العالَمينَ ۝٢
    الرَّحمٰنِ الرَّحيمِ ۝٣
    مالِكِ يَومِ الدّينِ ۝٤
    إِيّاكَ نَعبُدُ وَإِيّاكَ نَستَعينُ ۝٥
    //
  \glb {به نام} خداوند رحمتگر مهربان (١)
    ستايش خدايى {را كه پروردگار} جهانيان، (٢)
    رحمتگر مهربان، (٣)
    {[و] خداوند} روز جزاست. (٤)
    {[بار الها] تنها تو را} مى‌پرستيم، {و تنها از تو يارى} مى‌جوييم. (٥)
    //
\endgl

\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Thank you. Again, well done. I'll check it out soon.

Comment: Dear @DavidPurton , this solution produces very good-looking results, however interacting with the text to adjust exactly which word should sit in the right place is exhausting. To expose my standpoint, I will post it as an update to your answer so that i can ask you a question on it.

Comment: You're right, the result isn't favorable. I will delete the answer since you have included the idea in your updated answer. Thank you again for your time.

Comment: @AlirezaFarhadiK., I think you are going to struggle to get a completely automatic outcome without some manual intervention. Maybe you could type some an occasional *ayah* with manual breaks?

Comment: Like what ? Does that solve the justifying issue?

Comment: @AlirezaFarhadiK., How about my latest update?

Comment: Dear Mr @DavidPurton ,It seems nice. Thank you, I will check it soon.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an answer. (i don't have Yas font so Amiri is used for both Arabe and Persian).

```
\documentclass[b5paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[left=1.8cm,right=1.8cm,top=3cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{arabxetex}
\usepackage[trans=fa]{quran}
\usepackage{xepersian}
\settextfont[Scale=.7]{Amiri}

\newfontfamily\Amiri[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}

\newif\ifwecanrepeat
\newsavebox\quranar
\newsavebox\quranfr
\newsavebox\qurantemp

\makeatletter 
\newcommand{\quransurahAF}[1][\qt@surah@default]{%
\setbox\quranar=\vbox{%
  \begin{arab}
    \noindent\Amiri\quransurah*[#1]
  \end{arab}}%
\setbox\quranfr=\vbox{%
  \noindent
  \quransurahfa*[#1]}%
\loop
  \ifvoid\quranar
    \wecanrepeatfalse\unvbox\quranfr
  \else\ifvoid\quranfr
    \wecanrepeatfalse\unvbox\quranar
  \else
    \wecanrepeattrue
    \setbox\qurantemp=\vsplit\quranar to \baselineskip \unvbox\qurantemp
    \setbox\qurantemp=\vsplit\quranfr to \baselineskip \unvbox\qurantemp
  \fi\fi
\ifwecanrepeat\repeat}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\quransurahAF[97]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Dear @touhami, usually the number of characters of the translated text exceed the original one, so they wont end at the same time (especially for long texts e.g.  `\quransurahAF[2]` in the code) . Do you think is it possible to have the numbers placed below each other?

Comment: @AlirezaFarhadiK. Sorry, but no.